# Capybara Ruby On Rails Login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, capybara, bdd, rspec-rails

I have been trying to get the user login to be able to work but have no luck.  Please help me understand capybara and rspec better, im fairly new to this.

spec/features/login_spec.rb

```
# User Behavior

describe User do 
  it "Can login" do
    visit root_path
    click_on "Login"
    expect(page).to have_text("Login to your account")
    within ".simple_form" do
        fill_in "Email", with: "user@test.com"
        fill_in "Password", with: 'password'
        click_on "Log In"
        subject.save!
    end
  end
end
```

devise/sessions/new.html.erb

```
<div class="container content">   
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
      <div class="reg-page">
        <div class="reg-header">            
          <h2>Login to your account</h2>
        </div>
        <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
        <div class="input-group margin-bottom-20">
          <%= f.input :email, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>                    
        <div class="input-group margin-bottom-20">
          <%= f.input :password, autocomplete: "off", class: 'password form-control' %>
        </div>                    
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
                <%= f.label :remember_me %>
              </div>
            <% end %>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="actions">
                <%= f.button :submit, "Log In", class: 'btn btn-u-lg btn-u' %>
              </div>                          
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <% end %>
        <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
      </div>            
    </div>
  </div><!--/row-->
</div>
```

rspec error

F..

Failures:

```
 1) User Can login
     Failure/Error: subject.save!
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Email can't be blank, Password can't be blank
```

gemfile

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
end
```

spec_helper.rb

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Needed to have a user already created in the DB for capybara to refer to!